# Switching out implementation source files in C project

Tags: c, compiler, modularization, clang

For simplicity, let's say I have the following C project structure:

```
src/
  utils/
    logger.c
    logger.h
   main.c
   secondary_component.c
```

`main.c` starts with:

```
#include "utils/logger.h"
```

I would like to keep the code and its structure as-is, but stub out `logger.c`, `logger.h` and avoid compiling `secondary_component.c` (i.e. only use the subset of `main` and `logger`). For instance, instead of the regular `logger.c` writing to a file, the stubbed version would include a simple `printf`.

My attempted solution: create an extra folder `stubbed_src/utils` and place my new `logger.c`, `logger.h` inside that folder. Then, I perform:

`clang -iquote stubbed_src -iquote src -o main_proj main.c stubbed_src/utils/logger.c`

The goal is that when clang sees the `#include logger.h` in `main.c`, it will first look at the `stubbed_src` folder and find it (and thereby ignore the original `src/utils/logger.h`). Unfortunately, clang always looks at the *current folder* first (i.e. it looks for `utils/logger.h` starting at `src`, where `main.c` is located) and only if it doesn't find it will it then looks at the iquote folders. In which case, it will always stop when it finds the implementation in `src/utils`.

There used to be a clang command line [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11605515/299080) which disabled this current working directory behavior, but it has since been deprecated.

If I were willing to change `main.c`'s `#include` to be an angle bracketed `#include`, then using `-I` would also solve the problem since `-I` has no such restriction regarding the current directory. But this would be an [improper usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/299080) of angle brackets, and also I'm unable to change `main.c` in this case.

Ideally, my stubbed versions of `logger.c`, `logger.h` would be much reduced in size and only implement functions used in `main.c`. For instance, I would like to discard any `logger` functions called by `secondary_component.c` since I only want to compile `main.c`. In addition, those extraneous functions called by `secondary_component.c` introduce their own `#include` requirements into the original `logger` files and I'm trying to avoid compiling those extra `#includes`. I would like to be able to simply compile `main.c` and have it work with stubbed `logger` functions and be able to avoid compiling any extra files.

Any other suggestions on how to use an alternative/stubbed out implementation of `logger.c`, `logger.h`?

Comment: Change the current folder to `stubbed_src` before invoking Clang?

Comment: Is the stubbed-out version of `logger.h` different from the original? In what way? Usually header files only contain function prototypes, forward declarations, and other "parts of the API contract," so you would not normally want to stub out a header. What part of the header are you trying to stub out, and why?

Comment: Good point.  In other words, the header file is not likely to change.  Your implementation (.c file) will, however.

Comment: @Kevin For instance, `logger.h` has a function not used by `main.c` (but used by some other file). That extra function results in extra `#include`'s in the header file (for instance, if the function prototype includes named structs specified elsewhere). One of my primary goals is to avoid compiling a long chain of `#include`'s if they're not at all needed for simply compiling `main.c`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The idea of 'current working directory' for purposes of clang compilation is relative the *file currently being compiled* (and *not* relative to where clang is being executed on the command line). So no matter where clang is invoked, as long as `main.c` is inside of `src`, then `src` will always be the current working directory for `main.c` compilation.

Comment: But if `main.c` doesn't call your logging function, then you don't need to include `logger.h`, right?  Conversely, if one of your other C files calls your logging function, you'll have to always include `logger.h` *even if you're using a different implementation of your logging function.*

Comment: This seems especially relevant: https://cgreen-devs.github.io/index.html#_what_is_cgreen

Comment: @RobertHarvey `main.c` *does* call some functions in `logger`, but not all of the `logger` functions.

Comment: Does that matter?  You don't use all of the functions in `stdio.h` either.

Comment: To be clear, what I'm saying is that, when you stub or mock your logger implementation, you're not replacing `logger.h`, you're replacing `logger.c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal practice when mocking functions in C (or otherwise using different implementations) is to use different .c source files in your build process. Normally, header files are not replaced.

If header files really must be replaced, then the `#include "header.h"` include directive must *not* refer to a file that can be found directly from the current source's directory.  The C standard specifies that the `#include "..."` form must always first look in the current directory before starting to look into other paths.